# I want to put response from jquery $.ajax() method to a target <div> inside bootstrap popup Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm calling an ActionMehod using jquery .ajax() function and want to put the response into a target DIV tag defined inside the Bootstrap PopupModal.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: { "id": idVal },
    contentType : "application/json",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetAssetCalcert", "SiteReport")',
    target: "#popupModel",
    success: ShowPopup()
});

function ShowPopup() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
    $("#loadCalcert").attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
}
```

Here `"#myModal"` is the Id of BootstrapModal and `"#popupModel"` is the DivID inside modal-body tag.

This actually makes the call to actionMethod successfully and I'm getting the HTML response as confirmed doing `console.log(data)` on success. But Opens an empty popupModal and not rendering what is received.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to pass the return value from the success to the function if you want to put it into the modal:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: { "id": idVal },
    contentType : "application/json",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetAssetCalcert", "SiteReport")',
    target: "#popupModel",
    success: function(result) { 
      ShowPopup(result);
    }
});

function ShowPopup(result) {
    $('#myModal').html($(result).text());
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
    $("#loadCalcert").attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
}
```

Comment: $.load() is also quite handy. saves you some code lines.

Comment: why use $(result).text()?

Comment: it could have been just result depending on what's returned.  I just clipped from what I have in another project.

Comment: @Avitus I did as you suggested, this time Modal doesn't popup but the page got blured and i can see html text rendered within the blured page on top of the actual background page.

Comment: Do a console.log of the result in the showpopup function and see the value and make sure you don't have other javascript errors.

Comment: Yeah already did that, the console shows the complete HTML received. but the text getting rendered on blurred screen is everything included in HTML except all the tags like all the angle brackets. only text, labels and values are there and css stylings

Comment: So i did it by making this call `$('#myModal').find('div #popupModel').html(data)`

Thanks for the help @Avitus